# For loop for multidimensional arrays' indices not for (1,1,1)→(2,1,1)→... but (1,1,1)→(1,1,2)→... in Julia

Tags: loops, julia

---

I use Julia 1.9.0.
I want to make a for loop for each element in a multidimensional array.
I think the naive way is below:

```
T = rand(3,3,3)
for idx in CartesianIndices(Tuple(size(T)))
    @show idx
end
# idx = CartesianIndex(1,1,1)
# idx = CartesianIndex(2,1,1)
# idx = CartesinaIndex(3,1,1)
.
.
.
# idx = CartesianIndex(3,3,3)
```

But I want to access each element in the order (1,1,1)→(1,1,2)→(1,1,3)→...→(3,3,3).

Then, I wrote the following code:

```
T = rand(3,3,3)
D = ndims(T)
for idx in permutedims(CartesianIndices(Tuple(size(X))),D:-1:1)
    @show idx
end
# idx = CartesianIndex(1,1,1)
# idx = CartesianIndex(1,1,2)
# idx = CartesinaIndex(1,1,3)
.
.
.
# idx = CartesianIndex(3,3,3)
```

It works. But is there any more simple way?

Comment: Maybe `permutedims(CartesianIndices(T),ndims(T):-1:1)` ?

Comment: are you okay with them becoming tuples? or must they stay cartesian indices?

Comment: A comment and a question: There is no reason to write `CartesianIndices(Tuple(size(T)))`. since `size(T)` is _already_ a `Tuple`, and anyway you should just write `CartesianIndices(T)`. My question is: are you sure you need the reverse order? The current order is optimal for column-major arrays, why do you want to reverse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For constructing the iterator, the following is probably the fastest, since it is lazy and the runtime does not depend on the array size:

```
PermutedDimsArray(CartesianIndices(A), reverse(ntuple(i->i, ndims(A))))
```

This is significantly faster than using `permutedims`. Using a tuple instead of `ndims(A):-1:1` is also advantageous, since then the size is a compile-time constant.

(There is no need to write `size(A)`, since `CartesianIndices` works directly on `A`; and furthermore, `size(A)` is a `Tuple`, so writing `Tuple(size(A))` is redundant.)

I did not check which is faster to actually iterate over, which may also be a significant concern.

Answer (score 1):

I case the order of the `CartesianIndices` is needed `permutedims(CartesianIndices(A),ndims(A):-1:1)` would be an option. In case the order of the element values is needed it is possible to permute the array.

```
A = reshape(1:8, 2, 2, 2)

for i in permutedims(CartesianIndices(A),ndims(A):-1:1)
  @show i
end
#i = CartesianIndex(1, 1, 1)
#i = CartesianIndex(1, 1, 2)
#i = CartesianIndex(1, 2, 1)
#i = CartesianIndex(1, 2, 2)
#i = CartesianIndex(2, 1, 1)
#i = CartesianIndex(2, 1, 2)
#i = CartesianIndex(2, 2, 1)
#i = CartesianIndex(2, 2, 2)

for i in permutedims(CartesianIndices(A),ndims(A):-1:1)
  @show A[i]
end
#A[i] = 1
#A[i] = 5
#A[i] = 3
#A[i] = 7
#A[i] = 2
#A[i] = 6
#A[i] = 4
#A[i] = 8

B = permutedims(A, ndims(A):-1:1)
for i in CartesianIndices(B)
  @show B[i]
end
#B[i] = 1
#B[i] = 5
#B[i] = 3
#B[i] = 7
#B[i] = 2
#B[i] = 6
#B[i] = 4
#B[i] = 8
```

---

Benchmark

```
using BenchmarkTools

A = rand(100, 100, 100)

@btime begin
  B = permutedims($A, ndims($A):-1:1)
  for i in CartesianIndices(B)
    B[i] += 1.;
  end
end
#  3.386 ms (6 allocations: 7.63 MiB)

@btime for i in permutedims(CartesianIndices($A),ndims($A):-1:1)
  $A[i] += 1.;
end
#  9.877 ms (16 allocations: 22.89 MiB)

@btime for i in PermutedDimsArray(CartesianIndices($A), reverse(ntuple(i->i, ndims($A))))
  $A[i] += 1.;
end
#  67.359 ms (2000005 allocations: 137.33 MiB)

@btime begin
  B = PermutedDimsArray($A, reverse(ntuple(i->i, ndims($A))))
  for i in CartesianIndices(B)
    B[i] += 1.;
  end
end
#  112.968 ms (6000005 allocations: 152.59 MiB)

### Without using $

@btime begin
  B = permutedims(A, ndims(A):-1:1)
  for i in CartesianIndices(B)
    B[i] += 1.;
  end
end
#  110.022 ms (5000007 allocations: 160.22 MiB)

@btime for i in permutedims(CartesianIndices(A),ndims(A):-1:1)
  A[i] += 1.;
end
#  127.824 ms (4999508 allocations: 144.95 MiB)

@btime begin
  B = PermutedDimsArray(A, reverse(ntuple(i->i, ndims(A))))
  for i in CartesianIndices(B)
    B[i] += 1.;
  end
end
#  133.642 ms (5000005 allocations: 152.59 MiB)

@btime for i in PermutedDimsArray(CartesianIndices(A), reverse(ntuple(i->i, ndims(A))))
  A[i] += 1.;
end
#  136.936 ms (5000007 allocations: 198.36 MiB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another option:

```
Iterators.map(reverse ∘ Tuple, CartesianIndices(T))
```

On one benchmark it appeared to work better (i.e. zero allocations):

```
julia> T = rand(3,3,3);

julia> using BenchmarkTools

# OP method

julia> @btime begin s=0; for idx in permutedims(CartesianIndices(Tuple(size($T))),$D:-1:1)
           s +=  sum(Tuple(idx))
       end; s
       end
  804.353 ns (15 allocations: 1.30 KiB)

# DNF method

julia> @btime begin s=0; for idx in PermutedDimsArray(CartesianIndices($T), reverse(ntuple(i->i, ndims($T))))
           s += sum(Tuple(idx))
           end; s
           end
  909.115 ns (59 allocations: 3.98 KiB)

# This answer method

julia> @btime begin s=0; for idx in Iterators.map(reverse ∘ Tuple, CartesianIndices($T))
           s += sum(Tuple(idx))
       end; s
       end
  12.300 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

It's also a bit shorter (but cheats by using \circ unicode for composition).